# SolarPanel - effect of externally applied voltage

Tags: solar-system

Would connecting a 20V supply to the output terminals of a 12V

mono-crystalline solar panel have any damaging effect on the solar panel or do

the panel characteristics prevent any current flow into the panel?

Comment: This is not something which can be easily calculated or worked out using physical principles. It depends on many factors. Unless you wish to experiment with your solar panel, it would be sensible to consult the data sheet for the solar panel or contact the manufacturer, or ask in an online user group. If the panel is under guarantee, improper use could invalidate it.

Comment: the panel voltage needs to exceed the batter voltage to be able to charge it.

Answer (score 0):

Current will definitely flow into the panel - that's precisely what happens when you string panels together into a chain.

Cells act like two devices in one, a resistor and a supply. In the dark, the supply goes to zero and you're left with a resistor. The precise values are non-linear.

Like any resistor, when you put current into it, it heats up. Now a 20V supply is not a lot of power, so you're not going to get a lot of current, and basically nothing will happen. But as always, measure the total panel resistance with an ohmmeter to be sure you're not shorting it.

I have *heard* of some systems where they deliberately put current into panels in order to make them heat up to clear snow. I've never seen such a thing in the wild though.